# Record user screen on all workstations

Tags: linux, networking, monitoring, vnc, screen-sharing

Is there a solution to record the screens of multiple workstations running Ubuntu 8.10.

I was thinking of something that records using the vnc protocol (Ubuntu already has a vnc server installed by default).

Comment: You better not be using this for snooping around. Or else!

Comment: I have to record the screen of every operator in the call center I work at

Comment: Does it have to record EVERYTHING or would snapshot intervals be acceptable?  For example, screenshot every 5min?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This blog post "[Flawless Screen Recording for Ubuntu, Headless](http://technically.us/code/x/flawless-screen-recording-for-ubuntu-headless/)" explains how to use headless VNC in order to record screen sessions.

> It turns out there is a very good
>   recorder for VNC, vnc2swf. The only
>   problem here is that Ubuntu’s built in
>   VNC server (Remote Desktop) doesn’t
>   work headless, and I’d never pursued
>   alternatives since freenx is so
>   badass.
>
> [...]
>
> For headless you need the “vncserver”
>   package. It manages its own X sessions
>   and broadcasts them over VNC, as many
>   sessions as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think x11vnc is for you!

x11vnc -storepasswd and x11vnc -rfbauth ~/.vnc/passwd -ncache  should help you running the server and pyvnc2swf (debian/lenny has this package!) should be the right tool for recording through an ssh tunnel from one central monitoringserver

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark should decode X11 or VNC fine, you may need to aquire the .Xauthority file (MIT MAGIC COOKIE) to decrypt the data from the X sessions.