# Record user screen on all workstations - Windows Client

Tags: windows, screen-sharing

Is there a solution to record the screens of multiple workstations running Windows XP ?

p.s. I know is question has been asked before but that [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/11564/record-user-screen-on-all-workstations) is only talking about Linux clients. I need a (hopefully open-source) solution for windows.

Answer (score 1):

Not open source, but we use a program called Call-Copy to record VOIP calls AND screen info for computers in our Callcenter.

Answer (score 1):

If you can install VNC servers onto the clients the [VNC2SWF](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/vnc2swf/) program mentioned in Splattne's answer in the question you referenced is perfectly suitable for your Windows session recording, too. There's a sample video on that site using the software to record a Windows 2000 machine, but in that video he's recording localhost. Having it record remote machines is a slightly different procedure, but not a while lot different.

If you wanted to automate the solution you'll need to do a bit of scripting (or have somebody do it for you), but it's certainly possible to get a fully automated solution up and running.